# No Internet Connection Even Connected Iphone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview, reachability, cellular-network

I have made some apps with xcode7 (2.3) (Swift) for iphone and ipad, all works fine but there is one major problem in my Reachability, it says "No Internet Connection" Even i am connected to internet via cellular data but when on wifi it works fine..

The Webview still load in background but there is error "No Internet Connection Found" In front, so users will close my app as they will see the error..

please help me out guyz..

this is my code:

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

```
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {

        print("Internet connection OK")

    } else {

        print("Internet connection FAILED")

        let ViewController = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "No Internet Connection Found", preferredStyle: .Alert)



        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Destructive) { (action) in

            print("Dismiss button tapped!")

        }



        ViewController.addAction(alertAction)

        presentViewController(ViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

and this is my Reachability File

import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
    if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
    let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

    return isReachable && !needsConnection

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    guard let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
        }
    }) else {
        return false
    }

    var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = []
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) {
        return false
    }

    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)

    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}
```